# How to record call in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, call

I don't want to see "this is not possible in apple", beacause there are some applications which are already on app store and they record call conversations. So please give me some idea on how to record call conversation in iOS application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All active Audio sessions are put on halt when the call is active on iOS platform. It is not supported by Apple by design due to security & performance reasons. In short it's not possible to achieve what you mentioned without Jailbreak.

Comment: Is it still valid in 2020 or something has changed ?

Answer (score 2):

Apple Will not allow it. You can create your VOIP setup and then you can record call. Jail break is another option. There are Cydia tweaks which are able to do that. For example CallRecorder.

Comment: have any example for this(VoIP) process?

Comment: You can follow this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/150015/callkit-tutorial-ios

Comment: can i record audio from speaker which is not come from my app?

Comment: No this is not possible in apple